# Why does sorting twice produce a rank vector

Tags: sorting

This question came up after I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice/) .

There's a function numpy.argsort() that returns the indexes of the original array that would yield a sorted array. By applying this function twice you would get the rank of the original away.

Someone commented that "The first argsort returns a permutation (which if applied to the data would sort it). When argsort is applied to (this or any) permutation, it returns the inverse permutation (that if the 2 permutations are applied to each other in either order the result is the Identity). The second permutation if applied to a sorted data array would produce the unsorted data array, i.e. it is the rank."

But is there any mathematical way to explain it? I think there should be linear algebra formula to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I tried a toy example M=[D A E B C] whose rank is [3 0 4 1 2].

The rank is defined in this way:

If

> ## M*R=M<sub>sorted</sub>

then

> ## [0 1 2 3 4]*R<sup>-1</sup> is the rank vector of M

Let's test by plugging in the toy example:

## M*R = [D A E B C]*R =[A B C D E]

Therefore

```
R =  0 0 0 1 0 
     1 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 1
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0

R^-1 =  0 1 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 1 0
        0 0 0 0 1
        1 0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 0
```

Then the rank vector is

## M<sub>rank</sub>=[0 1 2 3 4]*R<sup>-1</sup>=[3 0 4 1 2]

Indeed!!!!

Now let's prove that the sorted index of the sorted index is the rank vector:

Let's assume that M<sub>1</sub> is the index of M and that M<sub>2</sub> is the index of M<sub>1</sub> .

So we have these:

1. ## MN<sub>1</sub>=[A B C D E]

where

2. ## [0 1 2 3 4]*N<sub>1</sub>=M<sub>1</sub>

And

3. ## M<sub>1</sub>N<sub>2</sub>=[0 1 2 3 4]

where

4. ## [0 1 2 3 4]*N<sub>2</sub>=M<sub>2</sub>

So based on Formula 1,

## R=N<sub>1</sub>

Then based on definition, the rank vector is

5. ## [0 1 2 3 4]*R<sup>-1</sup>=[0 1 2 3 4]*N<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>

Then, what is N<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> ?

Based on Formula 2 and Formula 3,

## [0 1 2 3 4]*N<sub>1</sub>N<sub>2</sub>=[0 1 2 3 4]

So

## N<sub>1</sub>N<sub>2</sub>=*I*

Therefore,

6. ## N<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> = N<sub>2</sub>

Plug it into Formula 5 we get the rank vector

## [0 1 2 3 4]*N<sub>2</sub>

Based on Formula 4, it is exactly M<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner way to explain it in simple mathematics. Let's denote the original array as $A$, the one after `argsort()` once as $A'$, and the final outcome after `argsort()` twice as $A''$.

Let's first be clear about the following statement: if $A'[i] = j$, then it means $A[j]$ is the i-th smallest element in $A$, by the definition of `argsort()`. Then similarly, if $A''[k] = q$, it means $A'[q]$ is the k-th smallest element in $A'$. Recall that, $A'$ actually contains the indices of $A$, therefore, the elements range from $1$ to $|A|$ (allow me to count from $1$ instead of $0$ for the sake of simplicity).

**!BOOM!**: That is to say the k-th smallest element in $A'$ exactly equals to $k$, i.e. $A'[q] = k$. Consequently, by the statement at the beginning, $A[k]$ is the q-th smallest element in $A$, which is saying the rank of $A[k]$ is $q$!

P.S., another more efficient way is to do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284703/22921422), to avoid sorting twice.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly serviceable answer to me @Leucippus